# Allow-Origin does not work when folder exists

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Consider a page served by apache2 on http://localhost/htaccess-test for example.

The folder might look like this:

```
htaccess-test
 |- .htaccess
 |- index.php
```

And this is the .htaccess:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Every call gets be redirected to index.php and handled from there by PHP (or whatever).

Now spawn a client *on a different port or host*:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <script>
      (function() {
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("PUT", "http://localhost/htaccess-test/foo");
        xhttp.send();
      })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Works. But if you add a folder 'foo' to the page's folder ('htaccess-test'), the call results in a CORS-error!

Can anynone help me to avoid this! I have an Endpojnt which has the name 'test' and that conflicts with the test-folder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> xhttp.open("PUT", "http://localhost/htaccess-test/foo");
> ```

If `/foo` is a physical directory then mod_dir will issue a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash. The redirect response won't have the CORS headers set since you are not using the `always` condition with the `Header` directive, hence the CORS error.

However, I expect you don't want the trailing slash in the first place, so you need to prevent mod_dir from appending the trailing slash.

Add the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Prevent mod_dir appending a trailing slash to directories
DirectorySlash Off
```

However, since you are disabling the directory slash, you need to ensure that directory listings are also disabled since the presence of a DirectoryIndex document (in that directory) will no longer prevent mod_autoindex from generating a directory listing (if the trailing slash is omitted). Add the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file (if you don't have it already):

```
# Prevent mod_autoindex from generating directory listings.
Options -Indexes
```

If you need to access any directories directly then you'll need to manually append the trailing slash as required (with an external redirect or internal rewrite).

Comment: Thank you so much, you just saved me and even explained what was going wrong. Thank you.